# Get unmatched objects between two object arrays in typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have two object arrays :

```
first = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "raza" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "sahir" },
  { "id": "54", "name": "ayyan" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "tahir" },
];

 second = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "razi" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "qasim" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "taha" },
];
```

I want to get unmatched objects from "first" array on the basis of their id, something like

```
const result = this.first.filter(e => this.second.some(({id}) => e.id ==id ));
```

It gives me matched objects but I want to get unmatched objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
first = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "raza" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "sahir" },
  { "id": "54", "name": "ayyan" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "tahir" },
];

second = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "razi" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "qasim" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "taha" },
];

unmatched = first.filter(item => !second.some(_item => _item.id === item.id));

console.log(unmatched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  *O(n+m)* time complexity solution (n,m are arrays lengths):

```
let h={}; second.map(x=>h[x.id]=1);     // we use hash map with "second" ids
let result = first.filter(x=>!h[x.id]);
```

```js
first = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "raza" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "sahir" },
  { "id": "54", "name": "ayyan" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "tahir" },
];

second = [
  { "id": "15", "name": "razi" },
  { "id": "3", "name": "qasim" },
  { "id": "1", "name": "taha" },
];

let h = {}; second.map(x=>h[x.id]=1);     // we use hash map with data2 ids
let result = first.filter(x=>!h[x.id]);

console.log(result);
```